# Can't run GUI applications as root

Tags: sudo, 15.10, gui, gksudo

I know i messed something up, i just don't know what, how or when. 
i used to be able to run gksudo (gui application)
or sudo (gui application)

and then i couldn't anymore - I've torn the whole Internet apart looking for a solution and this is my last hope please how do i fix this???

```
$ sudo heimdall-frontend
heimdall-frontend: cannot connect to X server
```

sudo nautlius gives`Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(nautilus:5327): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:`

i don't know if the server error i'm getting has anything to do with the lamp-server^ i recently installed?
`

Answer (score 1):

Since running GUI applications as `root` is a Bad Idea, I'm not happy to give you this answer: Read `man xhost`, then do `xhost +localhost`.`man xhost` also show how to set up this permanently.

Comment: i disabled access control, the problem is sill there

Comment: Did you read `man xhost`? What did you type to disable access control?

Comment: i typed xhost +